# Init Sub after loading presentation

Tags: vba

I designed an AddIn for PowerPoint with VBA. Slides can be marked and when you do your presentation these marked slides trigger something. The mark has a specific shape. So now i want to read in all marked slides automatically when i open the presentation in powerpoint (Doubleclick the Powerpoint file). I did:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
  ...
  Toolbar things
  ...
  Call Init()
End Sub

Sub Init()
  For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
  ...
  Next oSl
End Sub
```

I get an error, which is easy to understand. It says that their is no active presentation when i'm opening the powerpoint presentation.  But i don't find a way to call my Init() Sub automatically after loading and showing the presentation. Do you know how i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make your add-in respond to *Application-level* events. This is not terribly complicated but it can seem a little daunting if you have not done this before.  More information and example files can be found here:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Create a class module called `cEventClass`. In addition to the event named in this procedure (`AfterPresentationOpen`), you will also see many other Application-level events to which PowerPoint does not normally respond.

Put these codes in the class module which will establish the event handler object and a procedure to be run *every time you open any presentation*:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Private Sub PPTEvent_AfterPresentationOpen(ByVal pres As Presentation)
    Call Init(pres)
End Sub
```

In a standard module of the PPAM, you will need to instantiate that event handler:

```
Public cPPTObject As New cEventClass
```

In your `Auto_Open` procedure, ensure that you assign to the event handler and do **not** attempt to call the `Init` procedure.  The `Init` procedure will be called from the above named `AfterPresentationOpen` event!

```
Sub Auto_Open()
  ...
  Toolbar things
  ...
  Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Application
End Sub
```

I would also change your `Init` procedure to require a presentation as an argument:

```
Sub Init(pres as Presentation)
Dim oSl as Slide
For Each oSl In pres.Slides
...
Next oSl
End Sub
```